# jquery accordion extending

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-theme

I would like to use jquery UI Accordion widget on my site, for universal displaying messages to user.
I have a place above main content in MVC site.master where I check if some message is in ViewData["xx"]. The message has some header, body and type of message - error, info...

The Accordion looks like ideal plugin for serving the message in jquery UI theme, in default state displaying collapsed with only header while possible to expand it to see the body with details, however I am missing a X button for removing the message(the accordion item or whole accordion, if the removed item was the last one). Is it possible to extend the accordion with the x button for each item, or is there a better plugins for my needs, using UT Themeroller

thanks
kubiix